# Matlab: default variables to know the index positions in a matrix implicitly?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

The `ii` means the index in the `x-axis` and the `jj` means the index value in the `y-axis`. This example runs over a 2x2 times one-matrix. Does Matlab have some ready commands for the index values `ii` and `jj` so I can avoid for-looping?

**Input:** trying to find a implicit solution but requires the location info `(ii,jj)`

> h=@(a)a+ii+jj; h(ones(2))

**Intented output**

```
3 4      1+(1+1)    1+(2+1)
4 5   =  1+(1+2)    1+(2+2)
```

**P.s. Code-smell:** Explicit solution, not like this!

```
hh=ones(2);
for ii=1:2
   for jj=1:2
      hh(ii,jj)=hh(ii,jj)+ii+jj
   end
end
```

Comment: Where do the numbers `[3 4;4 5]` come from?

Comment: Maybe you want meshgrid? But more like use linear indexing

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin The input is `ones(2)` and then you just sum `val+ii+jj`, understood? Where the `ii` is the corresponding `x-coordinate` and `jj` is the corresponding `y-coordinate`.

Comment: I think I got it now, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h=@(a)a+ii+jj; 
h(ones(2))
```

As far as I know Matlab does not have an `ii` or `jj` built in like you want. That's not how Matlab works. I suggest you have a look at meshgrid:

```
Input = ones(2);
[N, M] = size(Input);

[jj, ii] = meshgrid(1:M, 1:N);
hh = jj + ii + Input
```

`meshgrid` generates two matrices that can specify row and the column coords of a matrix. I think you're getting too hung up on programming styles from other languages. If you're using Matlab, I suggest you try stick to the native best practice styles.

Comment: I think you need `meshgrid(1:M, 1:N)` to deal with nonsquare inputs.

Comment: @hhh: If you use `ndgrid` instead of `meshgrid`, you don't even need to invert `ii` and `jj`.

Comment: @Jonas Interesting -- could you elaborate on a new answer? I find the manual a bit dense here, some practical example? I did not understand the point about inversion -- hey I got it: ndgrid is a more general version so I could actually always use ndgrid in the place of meshgrid?!

Comment: @hhh: `meshgrid` is useful for 2D plotting. `ndgrid` is useful when you want to interact with arrays. For example: `[rowIdx,colIdx,pageIdx]=ndgrid(1:size(array,1),1:size(array,2),1:size(array,3))`

Comment: @Jonas so `[X,Y,Z]=ndgrid(1:2,1:2,1:2)` does not go through all possibilities for `(i,j,k)` where `i,j,k\in [1,2]` i.e. `[111,112,121,211,212,122,221,222]` so 2^3=8 possibilities. I did not get the point about pageIdx... Moved to new q [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563272/matlab-practical-difference-between-meshgrid-and-ndgrid-their-usages).

Comment: @Jonas Thanks, I'll try remember that

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
repmat([1 2],2,1)+repmat([1;2],1,2)+ones(2,2)
```

Suppose you want to generalize it:

```
myMat = ones(2);

N = size(myMat,1);
M = size(myMat,2);

repmat(1:M,N,1)+repmat((1:N)',1,M)+myMat
```