# Practical differences between meshgrid and ndgrid?

Tags: matlab

This discussion is getting dense [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562302/164148) about pageIdx with `ndgrid`. I can understand now `meshgrid` but not `ndgrid` -- please elaborate with practical examples where it could be used. It is not really the same as `meshgrid`: some odd inversions in values so where it is meant to be used?

Comment: From `help meshgrid`: "MESHGRID is like NDGRID except that the order of the first two input and output arguments are switched (i.e., [X,Y,Z] = MESHGRID(x,y,z) produces the same result as [Y,X,Z] = NDGRID(y,x,z)).  Because of this, MESHGRID is better suited to problems in cartesian space, while NDGRID is better suited to N-D problems that aren't spatially based.  MESHGRID is also limited to 2-D or 3-D."

Comment: @LuisMendo sure but what it really means/infers? N-D problems covers also 2-D and 3-D problems so why not to use ndgrid all the time?

Comment: @hhh: I use `ndgrid` all the time.

Comment: @hhh Probably because in 2D the y axis comes first (think of matrices: rows are y, columns are x)

Comment: @Jonas so you don't use meshgrid at all, you just acknowledge that the ndgrid returns the x and y things invertedly?

Comment: @hhh: Since in my code I use the convention of always storing values in matrix coordinates, rather than, say, image coordinates, there is no need for me to ever use `meshgrid`. Also, it's `meshgrid` that returns x and y invertedly :)

Comment: @Jonas Superb! Thank you, Jonas. Love this thing, changed my meshgrids to ndgrid :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you want to know the row/column/etc indices of an array. You can use `meshgrid` for that, but it will output first the column, then the row indices, which can be a source of error.

Instead of `meshgrid`, you can use `ndgrid`, which will give the indices in the expected order, i.e.

```
[rowIndices, colIndices] = ndgrid(1:size(array,1),1:size(array,2));
```

or, for 3D

```
[rowIndices, colIndices, pageIndices] = ndgrid(1:size(array,1),1:size(array,2),1:size(array,3));
```

`meshgrid`'s inversion of the first two indices can help when dealing with plotting, or with some of the output of Image Processing Toolbox functions.

However, when you want to calculate, say, the values of a 4D Gaussian, your only choice is to use `ndgrid`:

```
[xx,yy,zz,tt] = ndgrid(-3:0.1:3);
out = exp(-xx.^2-yy.^2-zz.^2-tt.^2);
```